Azure Private Endpoint with custom DNS
I have:
Azure Storage Account - storage1.
Azure Private DNS zone - privatelink.blob.core.windows.net.
I create a new Private Endpoint for storage1 - storage1-pep.
I open storage1-pep and go to DNS Configuration section.
DNS Config shows FQDN as storage1.privatelink.blob.core.windows.net.
How to create endpoint with custom FQDN like - my-super-storage.privatelink.blob.core.windows.net.
I know its possible as I see other Storage account configured like this but not sure how to replicate this. That custom FQDN was created by private endpoint as DNS record's metadata in the zone shows - created by private endpoint.
Thanks

For creating custom FQDN ,You can go to Azure Private DNS zone (privatelink.blob.core.windows.net). Click on + Record set to create a new DNS record. Enter the custom name (my-super-storage) and select A for the record type. For the IP address, enter the private IP address assigned to the private endpoint (storage1-pep).

@VenkatV thanks, yes, I know this, but my requirement is that custom DNS record would be added during private endpoint creation automatically, not as separate action manually. Once its added automatically then Azure removed it automatically also then private endpoint is removed. This ensures not need to do any manual management of DNS records.

As suggested in the comments, you cannot create a Private DNS FQDN with a custom name like storage1.privatelink.blob.core.windows.net from portal while creating the PE .
Instead of creating it manually, you can use the PowerShell script below to create a private endpoint and attach the DNS zone to the endpoint with a custom A record with my-super-storage.privatelink.blob.core.windows.net
You can refer to the Private Endpoint DNS Zone for the storage account here.

    $resourceGroupName = "RG-Name"
    $storageAccountName = "venaktstoragetest"
    $privateEndpointName = "storage-pep"
    $privateDNSZoneName = "privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"
    $customDNSName = "my-super-storage"
    $vnetname      = "vvvvvvvvvv-vnet"
    $location      = "northeurope"
    
    
    $storage = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
    $virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceName $vnetname -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
    $subnet = $virtualNetwork | Select-Object -ExpandProperty subnets | Where-Object Name -eq 'Storage-subnet'
    $virtuallink = New-AzPrivateLinkServiceConnection -Name $privateEndpointName -PrivateLinkServiceId $storage.Id -GroupId "blob"
    
    $privateEndpoint = New-AzPrivateEndpoint -Name $privateEndpointName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -PrivateLinkServiceConnection $virtuallink -Subnet $subnet
    
    $privateIPAddress = $privateEndpoint.CustomDnsConfigs[0].IpAddresses[0]
    
    $Link = New-AzPrivateDnsVirtualNetworkLink -ZoneName $privateDNSZoneName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name "mylink" -VirtualNetworkId $virtualNetwork.Id -EnableRegistration
    
    $Records = @()
    $Records += New-AzPrivateDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address $privateIPAddress
    $RecordSet = New-AzPrivateDnsRecordSet -Name "$customDNSName.$privateDNSZoneName" -RecordType A -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TTL 3600 -ZoneName $privateDNSZoneName -PrivateDnsRecords $Records
    
    Write-Output "Private Endpoint '$privateEndpointName' and DNS record '$customDNSName.$privateDNSZoneName' created successfully."

Output:

Portal Result


so if you open A record in the zone, on the right upper corner does it say that record was created by Private endpoint? if not, then this not what I need. In the script I see two separate parts, one is creating Private endpoint another one is creating A record. And should be that private endpoint would be creating a custom DNS record automatically, thanks

I'm my case ,it's not created any record with private endpoint.
